# Define friend user-defined literal operator inside the class

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does defining user defined literal inside the class [give error](http://ideone.com/E3JFLw)?

```
class test
{
    long double x;
    public:    
    friend test operator""_UNIT(long double v)
    {
        test t;
        t.x = v;
        return t;
    }       
};

int main()
{
    test T = 10.0_UNIT;        
    return 0;
}
```

ERROR:

```
unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""_UNIT'
```

Note: It is possible to define [any friend function](http://ideone.com/ni9CDK) inside the class.

```
class test
{
    int x;
    public:
    test():x(10) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, test t)
    {
        o << t.x ;
        return o;
    }
};

int main() {
    test T;
    std::cout << T;
    return 0;
}
```

The same friend user defined literal can be defined [outside the class](http://ideone.com/p4zE0x).

```
class test
{
    long double x;
    public:    
    friend test operator""_UNIT(long double v);
};

test operator""_UNIT(long double v)
{
    test t;
    t.x = v;
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    test T = 10.0_UNIT;        
    return 0;
}
```

Does this quote from the standard have an impact?

> A friend function defined in a class is in the (lexical) scope of the
>   class in which it is defined. A friend function defined outside the
>   class is not

Comment: when you do `operator<<(std::ostream&, test)` from `main()` it has to lookup the function and looks in `test` because its one of the parameters. with `_UNIT` the only place it looks is in the current space and `_UNIT` isn't there.

Comment: The key difference is `operator<<` has a parameter type that expands the lookup but `_UNIT` does not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you're running into is that, from [namespace.memdef]:

> The friend declaration does not by
>   itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup (3.4.1) or qualified lookup (3.4.3).

The way they are found is through argument dependent lookup, [basic.lookup.argdep]:

> When considering an associated namespace, the lookup is the same as the lookup performed when the
>   associated namespace is used as a qualifier (3.4.3.2) except that: [...] Any namespace-scope friend functions or friend function templates declared in associated classes are
>   visible within their respective namespaces even if they are not visible during an ordinary lookup (11.3).

`std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, test t)` is found due to argument-dependent lookup on the second argument.

When you define `_UNIT` *externally* to the class, it makes the function visible.

However, when you define `_UNIT` inline - it's not visible to normal lookup and the only argument (`double`) does not have any associated namespaces so there's no way for it to be found with argument-dependent lookup either.

Comment: So how can I avoid that?

Comment: @KhiemGOM Just don't define it in the way that doesn't work?

Comment: Can you give a code example of a literal definition that works? And also why did define it in the same file as main will make it runs fine but when I define it in a separate .cpp file, it didn't work?