# Invalid suffix on floating constant

Tags: c++, literals, user-defined-literals

I created a user-defined literal like this:

```
friend fraction operator "" _frac(long double val)
{
    return fraction((float)val);
}
```

(Yes I know converting from `long double` to `float` is not good but I just do this for testing first and then fix that)
But then when I call like this:

```
fraction d= 1.0_frac; //error here
cout<<d;
```

The compiler (c++ 98) says:

```
[Error] invalid suffix "_frac" on floating constant
```

Is it because `1.0` is considered a `float`, not a `long double`?

Comment: [This basic test](https://godbolt.org/z/vWEK4hqT9) seems to work for me. Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: *The compiler says:* -- Please state the compiler and compiler version being used.

Comment: I think you're probably running into the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328444/define-friend-user-defined-literal-operator-inside-the-class).